# how to to get selected value from drop down in JSP Page with has use for each and need to get id and the selected value from ddl?

Tags: javascript, jsp-tags

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">


<title>CompanyProfile</title>

</head>
<body>
<form id="Admin" action="AdminViewServlet" method="post">
<div id="users-contain" class="ui-widget">
<table id="Profile">
<thead>
<tr>
<th style="COLOR: #ffffff; background-color: #910029;">CompanyID</th>
<th style="COLOR: #ffffff; background-color: #910029;">ChangeStatus</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<c:forEach var="Profile" items="${requestScope.allProfile}" varStatus="status">
<tr>
<td>${Profile.companyId}</td>
<td><select id="statuschange" name="statuschange">
<option id="statuschangetype" value="">---Choose a type---
<option id ="statuschangetype1" value="Activate"> Activate
<option id ="statuschangetype2" value=" Deactivate">Deactivate</select></td>
<td  onclick="StatusChange(this)">
<input type="button"  id=${Profile.companyId } value="Change Status"></td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</form>
</body>
function StatusChange(click) {
     alert("change status");
     var tablerow = click.parentNode;
     alert("ha ha parentnode...");
     var companyId = tablerow.cells[1].innerHTML;
     alert("id...."+companyId);
     var i = document.getElementById("statuschange");
     var changestatus = i.options[i.selectedIndex].value;
alert("got status" + changestatus);
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
async: false,
dataType: "text",
url: "/Projectlogin/AdminViewServlet",
data: {ActionType:"5",companyId:companyId,status:changestatus},
success: function(TokenData){
alert("testing");
alert("response data: "+TokenData);
   if(TokenData !== null){
alert('Saved !');

returnValue = TokenData;

            }   
        }           

    }); 
}

 </script>
 </html>
```

Hi,I am a new programmer and I am not sure how I can get selected dropdown value from the row and  update it with companyId. As per above Code I am only able to get once. If I want to change on the next line it give me the previous changed value.
Please help me to find out how I can go status update from each rows.

Regards,
Ruby

Comment: Thank you Yagnesh. I tried but it is giving me no value. Regards,Ruby

Answer (score 0):

It is because at line

```
var i = document.getElementById("statuschange");
```

It always select the first row dropdown because all dropdown has same id.
Give dropdown id as companyId and replace that id in above code you will get the correct value for each row.

You can give id to all dropdown so that all dropdown get different id.

I think his will help you.